# How to use sip_ua in flutter?Causes 50 errors

Tags: flutter, sip

I installed sip_ua pod in my flutter application. https://pub.dev/packages/sip_ua#-installing-tab- 
When I open the project in visual studio it shows more than 50 errors.I am new to flutter.I have no idea how to clear my errors.Please anyone help me.

[image]

[image]

I am having these types of errors.Please help me.

Comment: Try the following : Go to Terminal. Run `flutter clean` and then `flutter packages get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined your own class `IncomingMessage` and that's clashing with the library's version. You could either rename your class, or (as it says in the error message) import the library with a prefix.

```
import 'package:sip_ua/sip_ua.dart' as ua;
//
// now the library's version will be ua.IncomingMessage and won't clash with yours
```